# Inventory Management Calculated Field in SharePoint 2010 across 2 Lists

Tags: list, sharepoint, field

I need a formula to calculate how much inventory is left on had after a work order has been completed. The work order I am developing is a separate list in sharepoint and I have an inventory list as well.

In the inventory list I have a field called `amountinventoried` and `itemname` which the user would put the amount of the item we had on hand during the last manual inventory.

On the work order list I have a field called `itemused` and `amountused` I need to find a formula to use on a calculated field in the Inventory list that would go out and simply subtract the `amountused` from the `amountinventoried` but only if the `itemused` and `itemname` fields matched.

I have been working on this for quite a while and have hit a wall, I'm probably overlooking something extremely easy but I'm still new to sharepoint 2010.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this in a grouped view of the work order list ([sort of like this](http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/summing-calculated-columns-in-group-by-in-sharepoint-list-dataview-webpart/)), but I think the design of what you are doing is not suited to using SharePoint lists.

You may be much better off using an SQL database to host and calculate the data and connect it into SharePoint as External Lists using the Business Connectivity Services ([brief explanation here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-2010-external-lists.aspx)).

This gives you the benefit of CRUD functionality in SharePoint, with the extra calculations and trickery available within SQL views and tables.